# PHP work with Persian characters in scandir() and rename()

Tags: php, unicode, persian, scandir

I am working with a couple of files, listed in a folder named `states`.
Here is an example of where my files are exactly located:
`root/states/state_name/type_name/city_name.txt`
There are multiple states, cities, types and files in this structure.
I want to find every `city Id` in my database, then rename `city_name.txt` to `city_id.txt`

Here's what I did to make this work:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include('dbclass/Db.class.php');
$db=new DB();
$states=scandir('states');
foreach($states as $state)
{
    if($state=='.'||$state=='..')
        continue;
    $state_id=$db->row('SELECT id FROM target_state WHERE state=:state',array('state'=>$state));
    if(!$state_id)
        continue;
    $types=scandir('states/'.$state);
    foreach($types as $type)
    {
        $cities=scandir('states/'.$state.'/'.$type);
        foreach($cities as $city)
        {
            $city_id=$db->row('SELECT id FROM target_city WHERE state_id=:state_id AND city=:city',array('state_id'=>$state_id['id'],'city'=>$city));
            rename('states/'.$state.'/'.$type.'/'.$city.'.txt','states/'.$state.'/'.$type.'/'.$city_id['id'].'.txt');
        }
    }
}
```

It didn't work at all!
`$state_id` returns false and the `foreach` loops to next state.
I tried to echo $state in every loop, and returned some `�������� � �` characters.

> My problem is that PHP `scandir()` returns Persian filenames in a wrong unicode.

I tried to add a `header` on top of my code also, but it doesn't make any changes.

Any suggestions and comments is appreciated!